# Loading pem certificate files in Tigase server

Tags: ssl, xmpp, ssl-certificate, chat, tigase

I'm trying to load a SSL certificate sign by [thawte](http://www.thawte.com) in a XMPP server running on Tigase 5.2.
As described in this [howto](http://www.tigase.org/content/creating-and-loading-server-certificate-pem-files) the certificate is in certs/ folder, but the server rename it with .bak extension and generate its own certificate.  Anybody once faced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I figured out the problem. There was a missing [certificate](https://www.thawte.com/roots/thawte_Premium_Server_CA.pem). I've just include it and it works. More on tigase [forum](https://projects.tigase.org/issues/2232).